# php retrieve value from object

Tags: php, api, object, guzzle

I want to retrieve a specific value from a PHP object which I receive from an API call response, however, I can't get it to work.

The object (body) is in the following format:

```
object(stdClass)#29 (2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (1) {
    ["events"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(743)
        ["tzShift"]=>
        int(60)
        ["utcTime"]=>
        int(1551703477)
        ["upTime"]=>
        int(20953)
        ["event"]=>
        string(14) "DisplayTouched"
        ["params"]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (4) {
          ["x"]=>
          int(46)
          ["y"]=>
          int(194)
          ["dx"]=>
          int(0)
          ["dy"]=>
          int(0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value in the following way:

```
$body = json_decode($response->getBody());
$events = $body->result->events->params->x;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: `$body->result->events[0]->params->x`. `events` in an array.

Comment: Aha, thank you! I did miss that, this is solved